# How to update Spreadsheet Properties with Google Sheets API and Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to update `fontSize` from here:

```
sheets_api.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=ssId).execute()

{'properties': {'autoRecalc': 'ON_CHANGE',
  'defaultFormat': {'backgroundColor': {'blue': 1, 'green': 1, 'red': 1},
   'backgroundColorStyle': {'rgbColor': {'blue': 1, 'green': 1, 'red': 1}},
   'padding': {'bottom': 2, 'left': 3, 'right': 3, 'top': 2},
   'textFormat': {'bold': False,
    'fontFamily': 'arial,sans,sans-serif',
    'fontSize': 10,
```

With this command:

```
requests = [
{
  "updateSpreadsheetProperties": {
    "properties": {"textFormat": {"fontSize": 12}},
    "fields": "textFormat(fontSize)"
  }
}
]
response = sheets_api.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId=ssId, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

And get:

```
Unknown name "textFormat"
```

With this command:

```
{
  "updateSpreadsheetProperties": {
    "properties": {"fontSize": 12},
    "fields": "fontSize"
  }
}
```

I get:

```
Unknown name "fontSize"
```

**Update:**

This command returned no errors, but the font didn't change:

```
{
  "updateSpreadsheetProperties": {
    "properties": {"defaultFormat": {"textFormat": {"fontSize": 12}}},
    "fields": "defaultFormat(textFormat(fontSize))"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Some considerations:

Unfortunately you can't update the defaultFormat with an updateSpreadsheetProperties request.
As you can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SpreadsheetProperties) the defaultFormat is read-only: that means you can't edit it with any update request.

#### Solution:

You will need to use the repeatCell request instead:
This request is composed by two parts:
1. The range within we want to apply our format update (in this case it will be the whole Sheet)
2. The cell format we want to apply

Code:

So let's build a new request object like this:

```
requests = [
  {
    "repeatCell": {
      "range": {
        "sheetId": 0 //This is the index for the first sheet in your spreadsheet
      },
      "cell": {
        "userEnteredFormat": {
          "textFormat": {
            "fontSize": 12,
          }
        }
      },
      "fields": "userEnteredFormat(textFormat)"
    }
  }
]
```

Now, if you want to apply this format to the whole spreadsheet you could easily loop through your sheets and update the "sheetId" index for every request.

#### Resources:

[Repeat Cell Request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#RepeatCellRequest)

[Cell Data](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData)

[Cell Format](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellFormat)